# How can I invoke a field which has a function assigned in Class level

Tags: ios, swift

How can I invoke a field which has a function assigned in Class level?
This is the code snippet i am using:

```
class Foo {

  let alias = whatever

  func whatever() -> Int {
    return 3
  }
}
print(Foo().alias) // print out this is a function

print(Foo().alias()) // compilation error about missing argument
```

First of all, I know I can use Foo.whatever() instead.

but let me explain why I ask this question.

So normally if I am using playground, it is working as I expect if I have a function and then I assign it to a variable. It has exact same code but it is just out of class scope.

```
  let alias = whatever

  func whatever() -> Int {
    return 3
  }

  print(alias)  // print out function

  print(alias()) // print 3 so it is working as expected
```

Dont know why I cant invoke it in the Class level, if it is impossible to invoke it, why swift doesnt have compilation error about `let alias = whatever` in class level

Comment: what do you mean by *can't use this function after it assigned to a field* ? you can always do: `let s = Foo().whatever()` and the answer is 3

Comment: understand what you are saying. I will edit my question to explain my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** invoke it in the Class level because **`alias` is not an instance method, but a function which returns another function** (`whatever` in this case). And Swift compiler does provide `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` compilation error, as you've mentioned in your first code block:

> `print(Foo().alias()) // compilation error about missing argument`

You may invoke `whatever` function via alias like this:

```
let instance = Foo()
instance.alias(instance)()
```

It means that `alias` function has a single argument, a `Foo` instance, and returns another function. This latter function takes nothing and returns `Int`, that is type of `alias` is:

```
(Foo) -> () -> Int
```

Basically, an instance method in Swift is simply a type method that takes the instance as an argument and returns a function which will then be applied to the instance:

```
Foo.whatever(instance)()
```

Check the actual `alias` type with the following code:

```
println(Foo().alias.dynamicType)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need a computed property, this will work:

```
class Foo {
    var alias : () -> Int { get{ return whatever}}

    func whatever() -> Int {
        return 3
    }
}
print(Foo().alias) // print out this is a function
print(Foo().alias()) // 3
```